# how to remove the FormArray in angular2 reactive forms

Tags: angular

I'm having issue on removing the FormArray from ReactiveForm.

I have the following code :

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.survey = new FormGroup({
    surveyName: new FormControl(''),
    sections: new FormArray([
      this.initSection(), 
    ]), 
  });      
}

initSection(){
  return new FormGroup({
    sectionTitle : new FormControl(''),
    sectionDescription : new FormControl(''),
  });
}

addSection(){
  const control = <FormArray>this.survey.controls['sections'];
  control.push(this.initSection());
}
```

Now for deletion the formControl surveyName I just do

```
this.survey.removeControl('surveyName');
```

And above code is working fine for surveyName. But what thing i can use for deletion the form array sections. I want to delete the whole section object with key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should always use `removeControl` to remove both formControl and **entire** formArray from reactiveform.

**Things you have to pay attention** is that you should use `ngIf` to control not showing the removed element after it's removed from reactiveform.

see sample **[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-removeformarray?file=app/app.component.html)**.

Comment: Thank you for answer bro. your answer is good. i have passed 2 day on this issue. but i did not solved it. i was doing same but i was not using the nfIf to control showing.

Comment: i did it already but i have one more question if i have on level same inside it. then how we will do it?

Comment: mean inside the every section i can add multiple questions and in every question i can add  multiple options. now  i want to delete the options:[{},{}] array.

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan they are the same. If you have more problems, just create new questions. :-)

Comment: ok sorry you were saying about tick mark i forget it. any how thanks i have updated your code there for my main issue. first click add section then delete the section question array is my main goal now. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-removeformarray-i7ez7f?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan check again demo I provided. Hope it helps. :-)

Comment: no bro it's not like that i have send you my demo url  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-removeformarray-i7ez7f?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts   here i want to delete the whole question array like we have done before but this time on section question

Comment: im doing this    this.survey.controls.sections.controls[0].removeControl('questions'); but it's not working

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan refer this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-removeformarray-qgnlmi?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154344/discussion-between-muhammad-irfan-and-pengyy).

Comment: bro i want to add option control on click now again it's formarray can you tell me how i add it again after removing & can you give me your email? thanks

Answer (score 3):

use `removeAt()` method for removing the element from formarray

Comment: can you tell me the code how ? because i tried a lot on it.

Comment: your_array.slice(index, 1);

Comment: find the index position you need to delete in array and apply this slice code

Comment: what will be index here? my mean i have this.survey.slice(?). because i'm going to remove the whole object sections

Comment: are you going to flush all the array elements (or) a particular one

Comment: giving this issue

Property 'slice' does not exist on type 'FormGroup'.

Comment: i'm doing like that
   let control1 = this.survey;
   console.log(control1);
   control1.slice(1, 1);

Comment: i want to flush all the array element sections

Comment: just replace the current array with new one like this below

var a=[];

Comment: replace the array elements to []

Comment: {
  "surveyName": "",
  "sections": [
    {
      "sectionTitle": "",
      "sectionDescription": ""
    }
  ]
} 

i have above json now i want to delete the sections array with key sections

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2  just have a look at this link

use `removeat()` method

Comment: @MuhammadIrfan Use: `delete this.survey.sections` More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)